# VBA named range offset

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, named-ranges

I am trying to write VBA code that will select a named range, copy it and paste it for a certain number of rows. What I need to know is how to select the range of cells corresponding to the ones above.

E.g. I have a range "myRange" which refers to: "=$A$1:D$1$,$F$1,$K$1". I want to copy this and paste it in "=$A$2:D$2$,$F$2,$K$2" by referring to "myRange" in stead of to the string of cell references.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim oRange As Range
    Set oRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D1") ' Change this to point at the range to be copied

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        oRange.Copy
        oRange.Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Next i

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT**: OK, something like this then (to cope with disjoint ranges):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim oRange As Range
    Set oRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1,C1:D1") ' Change this to point at the range to be copied

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        Dim oArea As Range
        For Each oArea In oRange.Areas
            oArea.Copy
            oArea.Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Next oArea
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I need something that will function on multiple selections such as "=$A$1:D$1$,$F$1,$K$1"

Comment: Updated to cater for disjoint ranges.